# Tango with Django exercise 8.3.1 - Add page

Tags: python, django

I need some help to get add_page function running properly. I've done most of the part, but when I try to click to make new page I stumble on error 404 and my URL looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category//add_page

edit: Description of exercise available here: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/forms.html#creating-an-add-pages-view-template-and-url-mapping

Relevant files:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
)
```

add_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add page</h1><br/>

            <form id="page_form" method="POST" action="/rango/category/{{category_name_slug}}/add_page/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
                cat = None

    # A HTTP POST?          
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': cat, 'category_name_slug': category_name_slug}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

category.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {%if category %} <!-- If category is defined we proceed to check pages -->
        <h1>{{ category_name }}</h1>
            {% if pages %}
            <ul>
                {% for page in pages %}
                <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}                
            </ul><br/>
            <strong>Would you like to add more </strong>
            <a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">pages</a>
            <strong>?</strong>

            {% else %}
                <strong>No pages currently in category. Would you like to </strong>
                <a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">make one</a>
                <strong>?</strong>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %} <!-- If category is not defind an error message tells us so! -->
            The specified category {{ category_name }} does not exist!
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I found already a thread of simmilar problem, but it did not fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated,

Alex

Comment: I still didn't find the fix, if anyone does, I'd be happy to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem so i'll post it for anyone who might come across the same problem as I did.

In category.html I changed

```
<a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">pages</a>
```

with

```
<a href="{% url 'add_page' category.slug %}">pages</a>
```

Please take note that the syntax of lines changed, because I started using [django-registration-redux](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is in your `category` view where you link to the `add_page` view. Here is the hint from the tutorial that I think you have missed.

> Update the `category()` view to pass `category_name_slug` by inserting it to the view’s `context_dict` dictionary.

Have a go at fixing the view first. If you are still stuck, please show what your `category` view looks like and I can expand my answer.

Comment: I added category.html as I forgot to add it before. Check it out.

Comment: I think it's the *view* where your problem is, not the template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
<a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">Add page</a>
```

with:

```
<a href="{% url 'add_page' category.slug %}">Add page</a>
```

in **category.html** and **add_page.html**.

Changing the code in **category.html** activate the link to add_page page.

Changing the code in **add_page.html** submit your changes.